# Initialize ETS cache using GenServer

Tags: elixir, gen-server

I am just learning about `ETS` and `GenServer` and I am trying to initialize a cache when my app starts. It's quite possible that I am designing this incorrectly which is leading to the issue I describe below, so any feedback on that would be helpful.

When the app initializes, the `:ets` table is created via a `worker`.

```
def start_link do
  GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok)
end

def init(:ok) do
  tab = :ets.new(:my_table, [:set, :named_table])
  :ets.insert(:my_table, {1, "one"})
  {:ok, tab}
end

def lookup(key) do
  :ets.lookup(:my_table, key)
end

iex(1)> MyApp.DataTable.lookup(1)
[{1, "one"}]
```

So far so good...but now I want to update that table. So I add a `call`:

```
def add do
  GenServer.call(self(), :add)
end

def handle_call(:add, _from, tab) do
  tab = :ets.insert(:my_table, {2, "two"})
  {:reply, lookup(2), tab}
end

iex(1)> MyApp.DataTable.add
** (exit) exited in: GenServer.call(#PID<0.157.0>, :add, 5000)
    ** (EXIT) process attempted to call itself
    (elixir) lib/gen_server.ex:598: GenServer.call/3
```

If I try to modify the `call` function to `GenServer.call(:my_table, :add)` or `GenServer.call(__MODULE__, :add)`, I get this error: `** (EXIT) no process`. Obviously, I'm doing something wrong with the `call`.

So I try to directly update the `:ets` table:

```
def add_direct do
  :ets.insert(:my_table, {2, "two"})
end

iex(1)> MyApp.DataTable.add_direct
** (ArgumentError) argument error
   (stdlib) :ets.insert(:my_table, {2, "two"})
   (my_app) lib/my_app/data_table.ex:17:
     MyApp.DataTable.add_direct/0
```

When I run `:ets.all()`, I can see `:my_table`. So finally I resort to trying to update it in `iex`:

```
iex(2)> :ets.insert(:my_table, {2, "two"})
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    (stdlib) :ets.insert(:my_table, {2, "two"})
```

Just to make sure I am not entirely crazy, I run this sanity check that does work:

```
iex(2)> :ets.new(:my_table2, [:set, :named_table])
:my_table2
iex(3)> :ets.insert(:my_table2, {2, "two"})
true
```

I must be going wrong in the server callback and just a fundamental misunderstanding of how `:ets` works inside modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems with this. I'll try to explain each one:

> iex(1)> MyApp.DataTable.add
>
> ** (exit) exited in: GenServer.call(#PID<0.157.0>, :add, 5000)
>
> ** (EXIT) process attempted to call itself
>
> (elixir) lib/gen_server.ex:598: GenServer.call/3

This is because you're calling a GenServer method on self. You should call that on the PID returned by `start_link`.

> If I try to modify the call function to GenServer.call(:my_table, :add) or GenServer.call(**MODULE**, :add), I get this error: ** (EXIT) no process.

The first one fails because `:my_table` is not a registered GenServer name. The second one fails because you're not registering the GenServer with a name.

> So I try to directly update the :ets table:

This is because ETS tables by default do not allow anyone except the process that created the table to write to the table. You can make the table public by passing `:public` as an option to `:ets.new`'s last argument. This will allow any process to write to that table.

---

There are many ways to fix this. One is to accept a PID in `add`:

```
def add(pid) do
  GenServer.call(pid, :add)
end
```

And then call it like:

```
iex(1)> {:ok, pid} = A.start_link
{:ok, #PID<0.86.0>}
iex(2)> A.add(pid)
1
[{2, "two"}]
```

---

Another solution is to register the process with a name when you create it:

```
def start_link do
  GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, [name: __MODULE__])
end
```

and then use `__MODULE__` in `add`:

```
def add do
  GenServer.call(__MODULE__, :add)
end
```

```
iex(1)> A.start_link
{:ok, #PID<0.86.0>}
iex(2)> A.add
1
[{2, "two"}]
```

Registering a process with a name also means you cannot register another process with the same name while the first one is alive, but that's probably fine here since you're using a fixed ETS table name, which are also uniquely named.

Comment: Great explanation! `GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, [name: __MODULE__])` is exactly what I was looking for. This really teaches me a lot.

Comment: Not setting the caches access control to `:public` bit me. An error code of `** (ArgumentError) argument error` was not very helpful either. RTFD...